Can battery brand affect performance?
I installed a new battery the cca, size amp hours etc is all correct.  It’s running ok but on start sometimes seems like it’s struggling to crank even in good weather.  Recently car was parked at an angle and I noticed I had to crank it 3 times before it started.
Connected a multimeter to test battery and battery is ok at 12.7, when cranking it drops to I think 10 volts and then slowly comes up to 13+ volts.
I posted this issue elsewhere and totally get that the alternator may not be wearing out etc so that needs to be investigated.
However since I’ve noticed this since changing the battery can the battery brand have anything with performance?  Could it be defective that the cca is not what it says?  Even if my issue is very unlikely to be battery related I’m still interested to know if the brand of battery can have an impact on the car and if so in what ways?
I was using bosch but I am now using a brand called power start.
Thanks

If you bought a brand new battery and it's not performing as you'd think it should, take it back to where you bought it and tell them such. They should exchange it for a new one under warranty. 12.7v to 10v seems like a pretty drastic voltage drop when under load ... have you thought about your starter may be at issue? Might want to get it tested, as a bad starter can exhibit slow starting as well as a large current draw when activated. Just a thought.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I’m pretty sure I’ve read on here before that when u switch the ignition on and its starting it’s totally normal to the voltage drop to even below 10 volts eg 9 but then it would go back up.  I think I’ve seen this with any cars I’ve tested in this way.  Do you disagree?

Did you consider damaged/corroded battery cable connections to new or old battery. Batteries venting vapors leave dried vapor deposits, powdery white/blue. When wet, battery acid works its way into heavy insulation, eating copper wires, weakening crimped connections, reducing current carrying to the starter. Batteries made for vehicles meet all vehicle requirements for high current demand of starters and recharging for reliable use. Examine battery connections, including one or two main grounds.

Are Power Start batteries lithium-ion rather than lead-acid? Will that affect the charging characteristics?

@FDryer you were bang on with this.  I’ve seen more corrosion previously so ASSUMED the little bit of blue I was seeing which was most likely left by the previous battery wasn’t the cause.  However a quick clean and as previously it’s starting right up!!  Thanks.

There definitely can be some differences between batteries, but the differences less from the brand itself than from the manufacturer, the specific model, and differences in shipping and storage.
There are tons of car battery brands, but most of them are actually made by a handful of big manufacturers like Exide, Johnson Controls/Clarios, East Penn, and Yuasa. For example, Duracell car batteries aren't made by Duracell, they're made by East Penn. Johnson Controls/Clarios makes DieHard brand, and Exide makes batteries for Interstate, etc. Over time, these relationships can change, and in some cases the same brand may be made by different manufacturers depending on where you are.
All of these makers produce various different lines of batteries with different capacities, costs, and lifespans. The difference between two different specs of Exide battery will be bigger than the difference between an Exide and a Clarios with the same specs.
Battery life is shortened by high temperatures, and a battery that's been sitting in a hot storage container for six months may not last as long as one that was in an air conditioned warehouse for the same time, even if it's the same brand and model. Batteries that have to be shipped long distances are more likely to get banged around.
And of course batteries can suffer from manufacturing defects just like any other product, so two different people can buy the same exact battery model and have different results.
In short, brand doesn't actually mean as much as you might think for car batteries. It's more down to the specific product you bought, how old it was when you bought it, and how well it had been treated.
I'm not familiar with Power Start brand batteries, I've heard of PowerStar, but I don't know anything about their automotive line, I've only seen them in motorcycles and such.

Basically you are saying unless the battery has a defect or wasn’t maintained properly before use it’s unlikely the brand is a factor, especially when the voltage is right etc.  looks to be the case as my problem was simply some corrosion left by the previous battery which I assumed wasn’t the cause.  Silly me.

Yeah, as a general rule that's true. If you do happen to get a defective battery, that's what the warranty is for, but with a fresh battery, the problem's usually elsewhere.
